# Validating Saved MongoDB Record

Tags: database, mongodb, validation, promise, nosql

I'm working through a mongoDB tutorial, and the instructor suggests I use the following code to validate the entry of a user into my database. I have already defined a User model, which just accepts a name, and looks like this:

```
it("Can create a subdocument", (done) => {
  const joe = new User({
    name: "joe",
  });

    joe.save()
        .then(() => User.findOne({ name: "joe"}))
        .then((user) => {
            assert(user.name === "joe")
            done();
        });
}
```

However, I don't understand why using the User.findOne function is necessary here. Why can't we just use:

```
joe.save().then((user) => {
   assert(user.name === "joe")
   done();
});
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: If you want to validate the entry, means you need to make sure that the data is really inserted correctly on the db. How to do this is, after saving, you need to find the data directly to the db using findOne, then you validate that data you are getting, is that match with the one you intended to insert.

Comment: Thanks! I think I understand –– the findOne actually finds a document within MongoDB, and doesn't just return the User instance that we just created, correct?

Comment: Yes correct, if you don't use findOne, it will only checking the created instance in memory, not the one created in the mongo, hence the validation is incorrect..
I've posted it as answer, can you accept it as correct answer? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to validate the entry, means you need to make sure that the data is really inserted correctly on the db. How to do this is, after saving, you need to find the data directly to the db using findOne, then you validate that data you are getting, is that match with the one you intended to insert